# Raspberry pi two network adapters

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi which I want to use as a proxy server. Raspbian x64

My ISP offers a public WIFI Hotspot where anyone can connect, login via a WIFI page that pops up in chrome and you have access to internet. For me personally, i just want to use the IP address.

On my raspberry py i'm connecting to my home WIFI with my first wifi adapter and then on my second wifi adapter (USB) i'm connecting to the public hotspot.

So when i'm able to connect my second adapter to the public hotspot, i'm not sure how to force chrome to use that adapter. My follow up question would be how to force the proxy server to use that IP and not my home one.

Comment: Remove the default gateway route for your internal network

Answer (score 0):

You don't force an application to use a network, but you add `route metrics` to your connections. This way when one of the two networks is available, it will be used and if both are available the preferred one will be used.

https://netbeez.net/blog/linux-set-route-priorities/

Comment: Thanks i'll have a read. could i use both simultaneously ?

Comment: generally yes but the configuration is more difficult, see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/775728/create-a-multi-homed-linux-load-balancer-with-two-internet-connections-and-one-l)